# Can i grab specific folders via Git

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to using Git and now i am trying on my repositories.
I have a repository where I have put many folders in it.

Now in my new project, I want to grab specific folders from that repository.

Can I do that in Git? I have uploaded my repo to BitBucket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: Do you want to create a new repo containing only one of the subfolders while preserving all it's history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need only certain directories, you should declare them as **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of your main git repo.
That way, those directories are in their own git repo, and you can clone them independently of the parent repo.

Otherwise, what you want is called **[sparsed checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout)** (as opposed to shallow clone, which clone part of the history of the all repo), and, as mentioned in "[Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial)", wasn't possible with Git.
Git1.7.0 includes it with `git read-tree` (but you still need to clone the full repo).
See "[Sparse checkout in Git 1.7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340860/6309)" for a script.

"[clone parts of a github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618025/clone-parts-of-a-github-project)" mentions other options.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible via sparse checkout, something I have explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738858/758345.

But we warned: You are probably doing something wrong if you need this feature. You should probably gives us more information about your circumstances and what you are trying to achieve.